# "Parsing error" When trying to import a DAE file I found on the internet

Tags: import, error, osx, dae

I found a file on a trusted site one the internet, but when I downloaded it and tried to import it to Blender 3.0, (Macbook) it says "Parsing errors in Document (see Blender Console)" I tried it on another document and got the same thing.

Both documents were "Whatnot_OpenCollada.DAE" if it helps.

Comment: First, update Blender. Second, if you still get the same error, do what it recommends and look at the console. You can toggle it on and off in MS Windows via an option in Blender’s Window menu.